# sending HTTPoison request! in a try and catch manner elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to send an POST request using Elixir Dropbox package, its very simple though

```
case ElixirDropbox.Files.upload(client, upload_image_path, image_path) do
  {{:status_code, _}, {:error, error}} -> Logger.debug "Error while uploading. Error: #{inspect error}"
  _ -> :noop
end
```

the issue is: The library I am using is doing `request!` instead of `request` and it's not giving any response in case of failure with a status code it raises an exception of `timeout` as

```
** (HTTPoison.Error) :timeout
    (httpoison) lib/httpoison.ex:66: HTTPoison.request!/5
    (elixir_dropbox) lib/elixir_dropbox.ex:36: ElixirDropbox.post_request/4
    (evercam_media) lib/evercam_media/snapshot_extractor/extractor.ex:132:
```

How can we handle such situation? in `try`, `catch`, `rescue`?,

what I simply want to do is: In case of any exception or failure, from dropbox API, I want to retry upload again, with , lets say 5 tries.

```
  defp upload_image("true", image_path, upload_image_path) do
    client = ElixirDropbox.Client.new(System.get_env["DROP_BOX_TOKEN"])
    case ElixirDropbox.Files.upload(client, upload_image_path, image_path) do
      {{:status_code, _}, {:error, error}} -> Logger.debug "Error while uploading. Error: #{inspect error}"
      _ -> :noop
    end
  end
```

Comment: What exactly is `ElixirDropbox.Files.upload` returning? You have `{:error, error}` in that pattern but you're saying the function throws an error instead of returning it?

Comment: Thing is. It doesn't return anything like that, just this error, according to that package code, it should return a tuple like that but it don't,

Comment: You can call that a wrong part. I only want to deal with that timout error through exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try`/`rescue` to catch this error:

```
try do
  HTTPoison.request!(...)
rescue
  HTTPoison.Error ->
    # the request raised an error
end
```

Comment: I am not doing straight HTTPoison.request! but its `ElixirDropbox.Files.upload(client, upload_image_path, image_path)`
How I can catch error coming through this?

Comment: Just put that line inside `try`. It should work if that function calls `request!`.